# How do you reload the latest save game in Kingdom Come: Deliverance?

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

I am trying to reload a save game on Xbox One X but I can't find out how. Neither do I find ways to enter the game menu once I have loaded a game. Now I always seem to have to restart the whole thing. There must be a better way, either to load the latest save game directly, or a way to get to the menu. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: @Wrigglenite Why did you remove my Xbox tag?

Comment: Because there is nothing specific to the Xbox One in this question.

Comment: Shortcuts differ across devices, though. As are the ways how you access a menu.

Comment: If you want to ask how to open the menu on Xbox One, that's different than what you're asking.

Comment: Not the Xbox's main menu, but the game's menu - as a way to load a save game. But considering that the save/load procedure is like this on all platforms, I guess it's okay to leave out the tag.

Answer (score 1):

**This save system is intentional**, to increase the effect of the role-playing element of the game.

Before the 1.3 patch

> players only had two ways to save the game: finding a bed or drinking
>   a liquor known as Savior Schnapps. However, patch 1.3 has updated the
>   complicated save system of Kingdom Come: Deliverance by introducing a
>   “Save and Exit” option that can be used at any time.<sup>*</sup>

With "used at any time" the writer means you can exit out of the game at any time, and once you reload the game, it will load that saved game. However, this saved game will not be accessible through a menu: **it will be loaded again after dying or restarting the game, and it will be overwritten once the feature is used again**.

There are several ways to change this feature however, as there is a lot of controverse surrounding it.

Here is [a manual approach](https://forum.kingdomcomerpg.com/t/if-youre-sick-of-the-save-system-heres-a-guide-to-fix-it/38689), and [here is a mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/kingdomcomedeliverance/mods/1).

<sup>* https://gamerant.com/kingdom-come-deliverance-patch-save/</sup>

Comment: Please take into account my explicit reference to Xbox. Your tips are for the PC version. I can't even figure out how I open the menu after having loaded a game.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Out of curiosity, why did you roll back my edit? To let the solution have a broader appeal?

Comment: Yes, there's no reason not to have that information. If the question is edited to specify there is a problem only found on Xbox One, then that information can and should be edited out once it becomes irrelevant. But as the question is right now, it's fine to have extra information.